# NSDictionary - use nil key or nil value?

Tags: plist, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I am using an array of `NSDictionaries` to store some baseball teams, each with a 'name' key. When a user decides he is interested in receiving score updates for a particular team, I collect which inning the alert should be sent. I want to store that number for the team selected.

I see two options and I'm not sure which is better:

1. All team dictionaries have an 'innings' key and for most teams it is nil (is it even possible to store nil for a number key? Would maybe have to use 0?).
2. Only team dictionaries where an innings value is needed have the 'innings' key - for all other team dictionaries this key is not present.

The second option seems more elegant to me - if there is no value, I am not storing an empty key. Is that right?

Bonus points: how do I use a predicate to pull all of the team dictionaries that do/do not have this key? My best effort is

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Innings != nil)"];
```

but I think that is expecting to find an 'Innings' key on each dictionary, and searching for a nil value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary in Cocoa cannot hold `nil` values, so in that case you either have to leave it unset or use a placeholder value for the case where you'd otherwise use `nil`.

If you know all the fields that you want to define for your dictionary, then you might want to consider defining a custom class with declared properties to hold them. In that case it is no problem to set a property to nil, and everything is more explicitly defined. The comments in your code will also help future programmers to understand what you were thinking when you wrote the code. Dictionaries don't do that very well.

Your predicate is fine as it is, but you can skip the brackets.